# Using LINQ-to-SQL with resharper

Tags: linq-to-sql, resharper

I am using LINQ-to-SQL and I also have resharper. In the repository I have a line:

```
IList<Employee> employees = DataContext.Employees.Where(emp => emp.CompanyID == companyID).ToList();
```

Where Payroll is an Entity.

Below I have a line:

```
if(employees! = null && employees.Count > 0)
{  
    ///TODO:                       
}
```

Resharper says payrolls cannot be equal to null.

If there is no match for companyId , wont employees be null. Can ayone throw more light on wh resharper says so??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no match for companyId LINQ will return an empty Enumerable, it never will be null.